# Array type on Vue Component Props breaks the Linter

Tags: typescript, vue.js, tslint

I am creating an AppProps class with an Array  prop ,  using Vue.extend...

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Component from 'vue-class-component';

const AppProps = Vue.extend({
  props: {
    test1: String,
    test2: Array,
  },
});
```

and then extending AppProps to create my component..

```
@Component({})
export default class ArrayPropsExample extends AppProps {
  get computedMessage() {
    return this.test1 + ' ' + this.test2;
  }
}
```

this is per the typescript example in the vue-class-component .  Vue is happy but the linter is complaining that it can't see my prop types on the class...

> 19:17 Property 'test1' does not exist on type 'ArrayPropsExample'.
>       17 | export default class ArrayPropsExample extends AppProps {
>       18 |   get computedMessage() {
>
> > 19 |     return this.test1 + ' ' + this.test2;
> >            |                 ^
> >         20 |   }
> >         21 | }

relevant code is here (https://github.com/JavascriptMick/vue-d3-poc/blob/master/src/components/ArrayPropsExample.vue)

If I set the test2 type to String, the linter is happy, but using Array seems to break the linter.. this is pretty weird and inconsistent

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I was able to work *around* this issue by changing my approach.  essentially bringing in the vue-property-decorator and setting script=false in my tsconfig...

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Component from 'vue-class-component';
import { Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class ArrayPropsExample extends Vue {
  @Prop({ default: 'hello' })
  public test1: string;

  @Prop({ default: []})
  public test2: any[];

  get computedMessage() {
    return this.test1 + ' ' + this.test2;
  }
}
```

I like this approach better anyway.